# css applying slowly with google app engine

Tags: css, google-app-engine

Whenever I update my webpage with google app engine, html works fine but css files don't get applied right away. And that makes me deploy several times. Does it have to do with cache? or something else?

my `app.yaml` is like

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: application/static

- url: .*
  script: application.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"

- name: markupsafe
  version: "0.15"
```

Hope someone could help me

thx in advance!

Comment: Try using CTRL+F5 just to double check that nothing has been cached wrongly. If the problem still occurs please post where you are calling your stylesheet and your applying it.

Comment: i am using mac what should i do?

Comment: http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Hard_Refresh

Comment: You can also learn how to use your browser tools to see which files are being loaded. Then you can see response headers like "Success" or "File not modified". It can help you to troubleshoot issues like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache issue.  For performance Google will cache static files on its front-end servers and in addition your browser may be caching them depending on the cache headers that are set.

As Andrei mentioned you can debug things using your browser developer tools to get a better understanding of what is actually happening.  However it's desired behaviour (for performance) if both Google and your browser caches static files like .CSS for extended periods - so while possible to explicitly set short expires headers it's not really what you want to be doing.

A simple reliable solution in my experience is just to use a different name for the CSS file each time you deploy (v1.css, v2.css ...).  That way the request can't return a cached version and you'll have expected behavour.

Through the use of a CSS compressor/minifier or tools like Sass/Less in a build process it is easy and also results in compressed CSS.  Some frameworks also may support it at runtime.